# iTextSharp JavaScript issue after editing pdf document

Tags: javascript, pdf, itext

I have the following problem:

I create a PDF document with iTextSharp.dll 5.5.11.0 including JavaScript. After creation the interaction with the JS works correctly, but using it on different reader versions and on different system summon conflicts with the JS.

Conflict: global JS variables defined in the document to get used in different functions get lost.

I try to analyse the PDF with Hex Editor MX. I new generated PDF from iTextSharp have the header:

PDF-1.4

but after you perform Adobe Save as option, a new pdf file will be created with the header version:

PDF-1.6.

I think this is the main source of the issues with JS. How can I prevent this problems after recreation?

[image: JS Error Message]

EDITED ----------------------------------------- 
Created: iTextSharp.dll 5.5.11.0
Testet Bugfree: Adobe Acrobat Reader DC | Version 2018.011.20038
(File Version: 18.011.20038.5321, AGM Version 4.030.00074, CoolType Version 5.014.00027, Basisversion 18.2816, JP2K Version 1.002.00002.39492)

Colleges edit the file with different version of Adobe Acrobat Reader but I don't know exactly the version of each one.

Test File (43Mb):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oa9RzMCy9MgQO5Ll0IMzJzDArtQstrEl/view?usp=sharing

I am thankful for every answer.
Martin.

Comment: Please **a** share the original PDF in question and **b** indicate exactly on which viewers in which versions your JavaScript works as desired and on which it doesn't.

Comment: The version of the PDF is irrelevant. What matters is: does the viewer support JavaScript? Many of them don't. Some functions work on Adobe Acrobat (the paying version) but not on Adobe Reader (for which you don't pay).

Comment: Hey mkl & Bruno I edit my post. I'am defiantly with your statements, but the thing is: colleges work with the document, everything is okay, JS do exactly what is should do, issues comes after over save (and new creation) of the source file. So how could that be?

Comment: The test file you shared from index 14221312 (=0xD90000) on consists only of 00 bytes. Is that only an error which occurred during upload to google drive? Then please share again without that error. Or is that true for your copy, too? Then that's the error.